# Calculating p-value based on Chi-Square vs Z-Test incl Standard Error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, p-value

I have been testing the significance levels for my various a/b tests.

Degree of freedom is 1 so there's not a lot of complications here. So far I've been calculating my results using Chi-Squared Test and for my .05 confidence level I got 3.57 chi-square which is just below the 5% mark .

However I have found a different way of calculating a/b results which takes the standard error into consideration and calculates z-score and then p-value which is a lot different.

First test produced `3.57` chi-squared which gives me `p-value 0.065` but the z-test produced `p-value 0.031` which, of course, changes the interpretation of the whole test as the p-value is half of the other

To make it simpler I applied this to an imaginery marketing a/b test with two variants:

```
Variant A      244/634
Variant B    2468/5835
```

Those are the numbers I used   (conversions / visitors)

Expected

```
Variant A      266/634
Variant B    2446/5835
```

From this chi-squared equals `3.57`

Using the other approach

```
Conversion Rate
Variant A 0.4230
Variant B 0.3849

Standard Error 
Variant A 0.0065
Variant B 0.0193
```

And then Z-score turned out to be -1.87, running this through Excel NORMDIST function returns 0.031 as p-value

What is the better approach here?